# Both Class Library Need Reference with each other

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building an ERP Solution based on ASP.NET CORE 3.1, I create multiple class libraries for more Architectural. I m using a Generic Repository pattern with Unit Of Work. I m facing some reference problems, such as there are three Projects
1- ABC.Models, 2- ABC.HR.Models, 3- ABC.Accounting.Models

Now I need some models to Share with Each Other. I can manage another Project That Not Dependent on others, but My question is how many times I make New New projects for decoupling? I need a proper solution to resolve this reference problem.
If I use One Models Class and keep all Models is the same Project, then No problem will arise, but I don't want to keep all models in a single project.

Comment: You seem to already know the solution.

Comment: There is no way you can refer class libraries to each other. You need to take a step back and rethink the architecture to come up with more fine grained class structure.

Comment: You already answered for question. On your place I would think again about the Generic Repository Pattern and UoW because generic repositories often end not as much generic as you would want to and it is saving just few lines of code. The second thing is UoW. If you will be using EF Core then UoW is already implemented in it, creating wrapper for it is not the best idea.